# A determinant problem

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, determinant

If $f(n)=\alpha^n+\beta^n$ and

$$A=\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 1+f(1) & 1+f(2) \\
1+f(1) & 1+f(2) & 1+f(3) \\
1+f(2) & 1+f(3) & 1+f(4) \end{array} \right|$$

$=k(1-\alpha)^2(1-\beta)^2(\alpha-\beta)^2$

then $k=$ 
$a) 1\:\:\:$
$b)-1\:\:\:$
$c) \alpha\beta\:\:\:$
$d)\alpha\beta\gamma$

I have done the sum, but an answer isn't provided, so please see if I'm correct.

$$A=\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 1+\alpha+\beta & 1+\alpha^2+\beta^2 \\
1+\alpha+\beta & 1+\alpha^2+\beta^2 & 1+\alpha^3+\beta^3 \\
1+\alpha^2+\beta^2 & 1+\alpha^3+\beta^3 & 1+\alpha^4+\beta^4 \end{array} \right|$$

$=\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1+\alpha^2+\beta^2 \\
1 & 1 & 1+\alpha^3+\beta^3 \\
1 & 1 & 1+\alpha^4+\beta^4 \end{array} \right|$

$+\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \alpha & 1+\alpha^2+\beta^2 \\
1 & \alpha^2 & 1+\alpha^3+\beta^3 \\
1 & \alpha^3 & 1+\alpha^4+\beta^4 \end{array} \right|$

$+ \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \beta & 1+\alpha^2+\beta^2 \\
1 & \beta^2 & 1+\alpha^3+\beta^3 \\
1 & \beta^3 & 1+\alpha^4+\beta^4 \end{array} \right|$

$+ \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1+\alpha^2+\beta^2 \\
\alpha & 1 & 1+\alpha^3+\beta^3 \\
\alpha^2 & 1 & 1+\alpha^4+\beta^4 \end{array} \right|$

$+ \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \alpha & 1+\alpha^2+\beta^2 \\
\alpha & \alpha^2 & 1+\alpha^3+\beta^3 \\
\alpha^2 & \alpha^3 & 1+\alpha^4+\beta^4 \end{array} \right|$

$+ \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \beta & 1+\alpha^2+\beta^2 \\
\alpha & \beta^2 & 1+\alpha^3+\beta^3 \\
\alpha^2 & \beta^3 & 1+\alpha^4+\beta^4 \end{array} \right|$

$+ \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1+\alpha^2+\beta^2 \\
\beta & 1 & 1+\alpha^3+\beta^3 \\
\beta^2 & 1 & 1+\alpha^4+\beta^4 \end{array} \right|$

$+ \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \alpha & 1+\alpha^2+\beta^2 \\
\beta & \alpha^2 & 1+\alpha^3+\beta^3 \\
\beta^2 & \alpha^3 & 1+\alpha^4+\beta^4 \end{array} \right|$

$+ \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \beta & 1+\alpha^2+\beta^2 \\
\beta & \beta^2 & 1+\alpha^3+\beta^3 \\
\beta^2 & \beta^3 & 1+\alpha^4+\beta^4 \end{array} \right|$

Now, $\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \beta & 1+\alpha^2+\beta^2 \\
\beta & \beta^2 & 1+\alpha^3+\beta^3 \\
\beta^2 & \beta^3 & 1+\alpha^4+\beta^4 \end{array} \right|=0$

$\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1+\alpha^2+\beta^2 \\
1 & 1 & 1+\alpha^3+\beta^3 \\
1 & 1 & 1+\alpha^4+\beta^4 \end{array} \right|=0$

$ \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \alpha & 1+\alpha^2+\beta^2 \\
\alpha & \alpha^2 & 1+\alpha^3+\beta^3 \\
\alpha^2 & \alpha^3 & 1+\alpha^4+\beta^4 \end{array} \right|=0$

Putting that and taking common, we ultimately get:

$A= (\alpha\beta^2-\beta\alpha^2-\beta^2+\beta+\alpha^2-\alpha) \cdot B$

where $B= \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & \alpha & \beta \\
1 & \alpha^2 & \beta^2 \end{array} \right|$
$=-(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)(\alpha-\beta)$

So finally, factorizing, $A= (1-\alpha)^2 (1-\beta)^2 (\alpha-\beta)^2$

So, $k=1$

Am I correct?

Comment: The result is certainly true. The question is, how to give a short(er) proof.

Comment: Can you please suggest a method for that?

Comment: What if you put $(\alpha,\beta)=(2,3)$ and the apply Sarrus rule ? Then $4k=4$, hence $k=1$.

Comment: I'm not aware of Sarrus Rule. :(

Comment: But you should - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $g(x) = (x-1)(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$, a monic polynomial with the roots $1, \alpha, \beta$. Then the Vandermonde matrix of roots to g is

$$M = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 1\\1 & \alpha & \alpha^2\\ 1 & \beta & \beta^2\end{array}\right)$$

with the known determinant being product of differences of roots $(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)(\alpha-\beta)$. By considering the matrix $M^t M$ you will get the matrix of power sums of the roots, which is the matrix you want to compute the determinant of, and $\det(M^t M) = (\det(M))^2 = (1-\alpha)^2(1-\beta)^2(\alpha-\beta)^2$.

This generalizes the result to larger matrices too.

Comment: great answer!:D

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you are correct. But *assuming* that one of the given options is correct (which is safe to do in, say, an exam), it would have been enough to test for a properly chosen pair, say $\alpha=0,\beta=-1$. Then the matrix is

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}3 & 0 & 2\\ 0 & 2 & 0\\ 2 & 0 & 2\end{array}\right)$$

and its determinant is [easily](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#3.C2.A0.C3.97.C2.A03_matrices) computed to be $4$. The only answer which fits is therefore (a), $k=1$.

Comment: I was just beginning an answer: Since you need only to find $k$ you can choose values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ - you want $(1-\alpha)^2(1-\beta)^2(\alpha-\beta)^2\neq 0$ - and suggesting $\alpha=-1, \beta=0$ - but you beat me to it. I did want to note the condition, though, which avoids having to divide by zero to find $k$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for noting that. This is what I meant by *properly chosen* :). @Mark